# How to evaluate the limit $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} $

Tags: limits, radicals

How can I determine if a limit exists for the following

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} $$

By using L'Hopitals rule the function appears to flip flop back and forth

Comment: $x^2\leq x^2+1\leq (x+1)^2$  so $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}}\leq \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\leq \frac{x}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that if $x$ is positive, then $\sqrt{x^2+1}=x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}$.

Comment: I see so then the x in the numerator and denominator would cancel leaving a limit of 1

Comment: Exactly. We end up wanting $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+1/x^2}$, which is clearly $1$, since the $1/x^2$ part has limit $0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $\infty = +\infty$, use $x = +\sqrt{x^2}$, otherwise use $x = -\sqrt{x^2}$. 
$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} = \lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} =\lim_{x\to +\infty}\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2}{x^2  +1}} 
$$
$$
= \lim_{x\to +\infty}\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}}} = \sqrt{\lim_{x \to + \infty}\dfrac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}}} = 1
$$